# guid in com object

Tags: c++, com, guid

What parts of a com object recieve a unique guid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CoClass ( the actual object instance ) has a Guid and each interface implemented by the object has a Guid as well.

Comment: The type library also has a GUID.

Comment: Note that only objects that need to be instantiated through the registry actually need a GUID for their class.